# Effective protection function against SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection, sanitization

I found this sanitizing function in a free software:

```
function VerifChamps($valeur)
{
$verif = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? htmlentities($valeur, ENT_QUOTES) : addslashes($valeur);
return $verif;
}
```

The query is then done like this:

```
$login=VerifChamps($_POST['name']);

mysql_select_db(..., ...);
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table WHERE login='%s'", $login);

$Result = mysql_query($query, $connexion) or die(mysql_error());
$row_RsProf = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result);
mysql_free_result($Result);
```

How safe is this code? How is it possible to improve it to make it even more secure?

EDIT: the server is running PHP v5.2.13, with Magic Quotes turned on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that it's ***not safe at all***.

Here's what's wrong with it...

1. You're checking `get_magic_quotes_gpc`, which has been removed from PHP for years
2. You're using `htmlentities` to encode the string if magic quotes is on, but not if it's off (way to corrupt your data)
3. Why are you using `htmlentities` at all to send data to the database? It doesn't prevent sql injection at all.
4. `addslashes` doesn't take the client connection character encoding into account when escaping your data (which makes it very unsafe)
5. You're returning an undefined variable (i.e. `NULL`) making the entire function useless

Also, `mysql` was deprecated and has been removed from PHP 7. Use the newer [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension instead.

You can simply replace your entire function with the functionality provided by newer database APIs like [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) and [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) which offer [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and parameterized queries, which are already proven to be reliable and secure. The code you're providing in your example here is clearly ancient and very insecure.

Answer (score 2):

For many days, i am using [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function. It's a good function to avoid sql injection.

And, please avoid `mysql` extension.This extension will be removed in the future. Instead, the [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use prepared statements

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged